# Trouble with jQuery .css() function and position: fixed table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a table that hovers at the top of the page to change colour when you hover over it. I use the following CSS on the div:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#navbar td {
    width: 20%;
    background: #3399ff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

#navbar td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the table itself:

```
<table id="navbar">
    <tr>
        <td data-href="/">
            <div>
                Home
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-href="/tribes">
            <div>
                Tribes
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-href="/minecraft">
            <div>
                Minecraft
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-href="/dynmap">
            <div>
                Dynmap
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-href="/links">
            <div>
                Links
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#edit').click(function () {
        $('#editformdiv').slideToggle();
        $('#password').focus();
    });

    $("#navbar td").click(function () {
        location.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
    });

    $("#navbar td").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css('background','#33ccff')
    });

    $('#navbar td').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css('background','#3399ff');
    });
});
```

This works and the table is stuck at the top of the page. However, the table cell does not change colour when it is hovered over. How could I fix this so that the table cell changed colour when hovered over?

EDIT:
Here is the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <script src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css">

        <style>
            #editcontainer {
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            #edit {
                padding: 4px;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: #3399ff;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                text-align: center;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            #editformdiv {
                margin-top: 0;
                border: 2px solid #3399ff;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom: 0;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: none;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            #editform {
                text-align: center;
            }

            #edit:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="navbar">
            <tr>
                <td data-href="/">
                    Home
                </td>
                <td data-href="/tribes">
                    Tribes
                </td>
                <td data-href="/minecraft">
                    Minecraft
                </td>
                <td data-href="/downloads">
                    Downloads
                </td>
                <td data-href="/links">
                    Links
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="spacer"></div>


        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <div id="editcontainer">
            <div id="edit">EDIT</div>
            <div id="editformdiv">
                <table id="editform">
                    <form name="login" method="post" action="edit.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Login</b></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the entire CSS sheet:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#navbar td{
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

#navbar td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #33ccff;
}

.spacer {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.text {
    width: 65%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #3399ff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

div h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.text p:last-child {
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Uhm ... Table? For your menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `background-color` instead of only `background`

Also, can I know why you are not putting this in your CSS `:hover`? It will be better.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions and nothing happened. I changed the position:fixed to position:relative and it worked, but I want the navigation bar to stick to the top of the screen.

Comment: Well i just tested your code and my 2 sugestion, all three methods work, so your problems isnt here... The fact that it worked in position relative is disturbing. May i ask you to poste your entire HTML (including your head and body)?

Comment: I posted the entire code and tried it in another browser. Internet Explorer 10 seems to like it but not Google Chrome. EDIT: Firefox doesn't like it either. Odd that IE 10 works and not Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: You have a spacer who is hover you navBar. Add `z-index : 1;` on `#navbar` and it will work. Cheer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#navbar td").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#33ccff')
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#3399ff');
});
```

You can simply do this using your css:

```
#navbar td {
    background-color: #3399ff;
}

#navbar td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #33ccff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the background style for a :hover attribute in your CSS instead of in the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something similar to this:

```
$('navbar td').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color','#33ccff')
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#3399ff')
});
```

Or, as mentioned above, you can do CSS similar to:

```
#navbar td {
    width: 20%;
    background: #3399ff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

#navbar td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #33ccff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, check for js errors that are stopping your jQuery code from working.

Working example (exactly the same code you posted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        #navbar {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        #navbar td {
            width: 20%;
            background: #3399ff;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
            font-variant: small-caps;
        }

        #navbar td:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#edit').click(function () {
                $('#editformdiv').slideToggle();
                $('#password').focus();
            });

            $("#navbar td").click(function () {
                location.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
            });

            $("#navbar td").mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).css('background','#33ccff')
            });

            $('#navbar td').mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).css('background','#3399ff');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="navbar">
        <tr>
            <td data-href="/">
                <div>
                    Home
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-href="/tribes">
                <div>
                    Tribes
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-href="/minecraft">
                <div>
                    Minecraft
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-href="/dynmap">
                <div>
                    Dynmap
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-href="/links">
                <div>
                    Links
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```